# Problem on insatlling apk on android device

Tags: android

i want to install a non market app on android device by using given steps:

1)Copy the APK file you want to install to your phone's memory card and insert the card into your Android phone.
2)Go to Android Market and search for the Apps Installer application.
3)Open it and click on the Install button.
4)After it is installed, just open it. It will show you all the APK files stored directly in     the root directory of your memory card.
5)Just click on the application you want to install and it will be installed.

but When trying to install the APK file, I tried a couple of programs.

"App Installer" and "Apps Installer" both see the APK file on the root directory but give me this message "There is a problem trying to parse the package."

please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Might want to explain if this is programming related in some way. It currently sounds pretty off-topic for SO, and might be better for the [Android](http://android.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site.

Comment: I agree with eldarerathis, not really a programming thing. The problem though is probably that you are trying to install an app that your device doesn't support: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html. Check the logcat output for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you havnt, try checking the "install non-market applications" checkbox, and then just use Astro to find the application, then click on it, then hit install, should work just fine. from the home screen menu>Applications>Unknown Sources

Answer (score 1):

When you export the .apk did you do it signed or unsigned?  I could not get unsigned .apks to install on my phone (despite having checked the non-market app option), however signed apps installed fine.